# Modifying views of a parent from child state in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have few common views (like breadcrumbs, notifications, sidebar etc) defined in an abstract state and few other child states inheriting them. I want to modify a view in the parent (ie: adding a new menu item to sidebar view) when inside a child state. I think I can use `view-name@parent-state` to refer to that view, but not sure how to get it to work. If it's not possible, am I trying to misuse the inheritance behavior in UI-Router? What's the correct way to implement such functionality in Angular/UI-Router? Can I do this even without using UI-Router?

Here's what I was trying to do:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts',
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    "main": { template:'<div ui-view="main-content"></div>'},
                    "breadcrumbs": { templateUrl: 'breadcrumb.html' },
                    "navigation": { templateUrl: 'navigation.html' },
                    "notifications": { templateUrl: 'notifs.html' }
                }
            })
            .state('posts.index', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    "navigation@posts": { templateUrl: 'breadcrumb_mod.html' },
                    "main-content": { templateUrl: 'partial-config.html' }
                }
            });
```

Comment: If you mean you want to add another view aside from the 4 views defined in your posts states dynamically, you can't, you can however use data binding to hide or show certain things in one of the 4 views in the abstract parent state by modifying some common scope variable in one of the child states, which is referenced in the parent abstract state, since changes of scope properties in the child states are propagated up to the parent state.

Comment: which scope should i define these variables?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?